# How to install 'adium-theme-ubuntu' (virtualenv)

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm working on a Appium Python test script for AWS Device Farm. I get error while building the script as;
**Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement *package-name (like PAM, Twisted-Core etc)***

I've already solved almost all of them, but still have problem with *adium-theme-ubuntu*.

This package is already installed on my system and virtualenv, but I still get same error for this package.

How should I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt install adium-theme-ubuntu`?

Answer (score 2):

I might have a similar issue here.
Got the same error while trying to import a requirement.txt into a virtualenv. something like "No matching distribution found for adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4"

Solved it by include --system-site-packages when creating the virtualenv. 
Hope it helps